# I hear noise after turning SIM7600 on

Tags: power-electronics, gsm

I have a question about the GSM 7600g-h module which I am currently  using to send data by TCP (Transmission Control Protocol) .

The problem with using that kind of GSM I bought is the noise after turning it on. It did not sound when I send data to the server.
What are the core causes of this?

Is there any way to settle it sufficiently without breaking?

[image: GSM7600H]

Comment: Have you read the data sheet to see if there are any clues? It might be coming from the inductor mid/top left.

Comment: Best guess: magnetostriction in the inductor due to burst current consumption.

Comment: @winny should I replace the inductor if that's the problem right?

Comment: if not how can I get it accomplished?

Comment: I have read https://fcc.report/FCC-ID/2AJYU-8PYA007/4857209.pdf

Comment: I just happened to replace the inductor with a similar type, nothing has changed though

Comment: Does it cause any issues? If not, leave it.